# Fastest Way to Count Distinct Values in a Column, Including NULL Values

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

The Transact-Sql [Count Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) operation counts all non-null values in a column. I need to count the number of distinct values per column in a set of tables, including null values (so if there is a null in the column, the result should be `(Select Count(Distinct COLNAME) From TABLE) + 1`.

This is going to be repeated over every column in every table in the DB. Includes hundreds of tables, some of which have over 1M rows. Because this needs to be done over every single column, adding Indexes for every column is not a good option.

This will be done as part of an ASP.net site, so integration with code logic is also ok (i.e.: this doesn't have to be completed as part of one query, though if that can be done with good performance, then even better).

What is the most efficient way to do this?

---

### Update After Testing

I tested the different methods from the answers given on a good representative table. The table has 3.2 million records, dozens of columns (a few with indexes, most without). One column has 3.2 million unique values. Other columns range from all Null (one value) to a max of 40K unique values. For each method I performed four tests (with multiple attempts at each, averaging the results): 20 columns at one time, 5 columns at one time, 1 column with many values (3.2M) and 1 column with a small number of values (167). Here are the results, in order of fastest to slowest

1. [Count/GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376564/fastest-way-to-count-distinct-values-in-a-column-including-null-values/7376726#7376726) ([Cheran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249624/cheran-s))
2. [CountDistinct+SubQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376564/fastest-way-to-count-distinct-values-in-a-column-including-null-values/7376580#7376580) ([Ellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis))
3. [dense_rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376564/fastest-way-to-count-distinct-values-in-a-column-including-null-values/7376995#7376995) ([Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569436/mikael-eriksson))
4. [Count+Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376564/fastest-way-to-count-distinct-values-in-a-column-including-null-values/7377117#7377117) ([Andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m))

Testing Results (in seconds):

```
   Method          20_Columns   5_Columns   1_Column (Large)   1_Column (Small)
1) Count/GroupBy      10.8          4.8            2.8               0.14       
2) CountDistinct      12.4          4.8            3                 0.7         
3) dense_rank        226           30              6                 4.33 
4) Count+Max          98.5         44             16                12.5
```

Notes:

- Interestingly enough, the two methods that were fastest (by far, with only a small difference in between then) were both methods that submitted separate queries for each column (and in the case of result #2, the query included a subquery, so there were really two queries submitted per column). Perhaps because the gains that would be achieved by limiting the number of table scans is small in comparison to the performance hit taken in terms of memory requirements (just a guess).
- Though the dense_rank method is definitely the most elegant, it seems that it doesn't scale well (see the result for 20 columns, which is by far the worst of the four methods), and even on a small scale just cannot compete with the performance of `Count`.

Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: This is quite a frustrating question. `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` so nearly does what is required and even notifies you that it has thrown away a `NULL` with `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.` but that would only be of use in a single column query where Cheran's answer would be just as efficient. Even in the case that the columns are not `NULL-able` however sometimes the `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` will be best and sometimes the `DENSERANK` version. Both plan shapes seem quite fixed however.

Comment: If you are doing this for all columns in a table with `n` columns the `dense_rank` version will effectively just copy the whole table and sort the copy `n` ways. I would expect it's best use case to be when doing a subset of (non indexed) columns where the non included columns are stored in the data page and quite wide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT ColumnName
      FROM TableName
      GROUP BY ColumnName) AS s;
```

`GROUP BY` selects distinct values including NULL.  `COUNT(*)` will include NULLs, as opposed to `COUNT(ColumnName)`, which ignores NULLs.

Comment: +1 Prefer Mikael's answer but this should be faster than the method proposed by the OP especially in the case that the column is not indexed and does not contain any `NULL` s then this needs 1 scan rather than 2 complete scans.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should try to keep the number of table scans down and count all columns in one table in one go. Something like this could be worth trying.

```
;with C as
(
  select dense_rank() over(order by Col1) as dnCol1,
         dense_rank() over(order by Col2) as dnCol2
  from YourTable
)
select max(dnCol1) as CountCol1,
       max(dnCol2) as CountCol2
from C
```

Test the query at [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112296/)

Comment: The [documentation for dense rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) states "If two or more rows tie for a rank in the same partition, each tied rows receives the same rank". So then this implies that if a 10 row table has the following values in column X {Null, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3} then max(dense_rank()) for the column would be 2 (since values 1, 2 and 3 would all rank at 1, and Null would rank at 2). If this is the case, then how can this be used as an accurate way to measure the number of values in a column?

Comment: @Yaakov - `1,2,3` have different values so would be ranked differently.

Answer (score 3):

A development on OP's own solution:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT acolumn) + MAX(CASE WHEN acolumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM atable
```

Comment: This does need a separate scan for the `MAX` bit but it looks as though only one such additional scan is needed regardless of number of columns and it does allow indexes to be used to avoid sort operations if they exist (and narrower less memory consuming sorts if they don't) .

Comment: @Martin Smith: Indeed, there are two scans, and I'm somewhat baffled by that. Can't beat the fact, though. Either way, thanks for the thorough analysis!

Comment: Although my method below requires two scans, in practice would it have any performance gains due to the fact that it is just returning the first row (if any) with a NULL in it. For a column with no NULLs this requires a full table scan. However, if there are any NULLs in the column, then it will need to scan only a subset of the table (and in a 3 million row table, if the first NULL appears at record 10K, you end up scanning many fewer rows). What do you think?

Comment: @Yaakov Ellis: This solution, being not the most efficient one in the first place (to say the least), would probably *not* beat yours when applied to only one column. However, if you needed to count distinct values for more than one column (in the same table), your approach would require two scans per every column counted, while mine, as far as I can see, would take one scan per every COUNT( DISTINCT) plus one for all the MAXes.

Answer (score 2):

Run one query that Counts the number of Distinct values and adds 1 if there are any NULLs in the column (using a subquery)

```
Select Count(Distinct COLUMNNAME) +
       Case When Exists 
                 (Select * from TABLENAME Where COLUMNNAME is Null) 
            Then 1 Else 0 End
From TABLENAME
```

Comment: Step 3 can use EXISTS to check for the presence of any NULL value(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
count(
distinct coalesce(
    your_table.column_1, your_table.column_2
    -- cast them if you want replace value from column are not same type
    )
) as COUNT_TEST
```

Function coalesce help you combine two columns with replace not null values.

I used this in mine case and success with correctly result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this would be the fastest but might be worth testing.  Use case to give null a value.  Clearly you would need to select a value for null that would not occur in the real data. According to the query plan this would be a dead heat with the count(*) (group by) solution proposed by Cheran S.

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT( distinct
                 (case when [testNull] is null then 'dbNullValue' else [testNull] end)
             )
    FROM [test].[dbo].[testNullVal]
```

With this approach can also count more than one column

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT( distinct
                 (case when [testNull1] is null then 'dbNullValue' else [testNull1] end)
             ),
        COUNT( distinct
                 (case when [testNull2] is null then 'dbNullValue' else [testNull2] end)
             )
    FROM [test].[dbo].[testNullVal]
```

Comment: This won't be able to use indexes to avoid a sort operation and what sentinel value can you use that is guaranteed not to occur in the data and works across all datatypes.

Comment: @Martin Smith Clearly can find A text value that virtually unique.   Even GUID is not guaranteed to be unique and is in practice accepted as unique.

Comment: @Martin Smith  I am using SQL Express 2008 R2.  I put an index on the column and the query plan shows that it IS using the index.  The query plan also has a sort operation.

Comment: @martin Smith  I looked at the query plan and with the index the sort is avoided on the count() (group by).  With an index the count() (group by) would win.  It might be worth testing multiple column in one query with the approach I suggested versus multiple queries using count() (group by) but count() (group by) would probably win.